# Are questions about Q# and other quantum programming languages on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, asking-questions

Q# is Microsoft's programming language for working with quantum computers. Are questions that deal with the language itself (e.g. *How do I initilaize a Qubit to a given value in Q#*) that don't deal with quantum computing generally considered on topic?

Comment: Definitely yes.

Comment: I would also say say.

Answer (score 17):

**Absolutely**.

They relate to both computers and quantum mechanics, and I can't really think of any other criteria for on-topicness.

(This answer is a bit brief, but it's really all I think I need to say.)

---

It would presumably be on-topic on SO too, but I feel like this is just as good if not better of a place for those questions.  I'm not versed in Q#, but I feel like the majority of users on SO aren't experts in quantum computing the same way users of this site are likely to be, and that would have a large effect on the answers.

See other sites, like Science Fiction and Fantasy vs Literature, where some books are on-topic for both.