# Off-topic reasons for Quantum Computing

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I suppose we should think about the off-topic reasons for this page.

As @Mithrandir24601 suggested I removed my proposals from this question and added them as an community answer. Feel free to edit them.

Comment: I think the 'questions about QM' one is worded a tad strictly (although the 'spirit' makes sense) - e.g. if I want to simulate some QM on a QC, it's not about applications of QM, but something that most definitely should be on topic. Also, we might want to think about 'programming help' one - what about tools designed to simulate a QC?

Comment: I agree especially with the latter part of what @Mithrandir24601 said - programming questions about tools and languages should be allowed as long as the questions are specific to quantum computers and algorithms. (So no _"I'm facing this JavaScript problem while building my quantum simulator"_ but instead _"I'm facing this quantum computing problem while building a simulator in JavaScript"_.)

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 done. I have enabled community wiki mode so that anybody can edit it.

Comment: It is **far too early** to define off-topic reasons. The time to think about off-topic reasons is once you have **experience** of what kinds of off-topic questions get asked. Think about it in a few months — or a few years — once you start to recognize a pattern of “yet another off-topic question about X”. Furthermore, each off-topic reason needs its own proposal thread, you can't usefully discuss every proposal in a single thread.

Comment: @Gilles I tried to include only reasons that have already been discussed in meta except for non-quantum hardware in my first proposal. And I don't want to discuss these reasons here but collect them. If you disagree with the reasons, feel free to improve them. they are CW

Comment: @MEE I don't know enough about QC to discuss off-topic reasons. I do have enough experience about Stack Exchange sites to know that this thread is not productive at all. A thread to collect close reasons is pointless. A thread to discuss proposals is useful, but only if the proposal is for something that could apply to a number of questions that have _already_ been closed.

Answer (score 7):

My (original) proposal:

- > Questions about **non-quantum hardware** are off-topic. You may get help at   [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com).

  ```
  Questions about **non-quantum hardware** are off-topic. You may get help at   [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com).
  ```
- > Questions about **quantum mechanics** are off-topic unless they involve their application to quantum computers. See [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-to-handle-questions-that-relate-to-quantum-but-not-computing) meta question. You may get help at [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

  ```
  Questions about **quantum mechanics** are off-topic unless they involve their application to quantum computers. See [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-to-handle-questions-that-relate-to-quantum-but-not-computing) meta question. You may get help at [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com).
  ```

  *or*

  > Questions about **quantum mechanics** have to be related to the *development, emulation or programming* of quantum computers. See [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-to-handle-questions-that-relate-to-quantum-but-not-computing) meta question. You may get help at [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

  ```
  Questions about **quantum mechanics** have to be related to the *development, emulation or programming* of quantum computers. See [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-to-handle-questions-that-relate-to-quantum-but-not-computing) meta question. You may get help at [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com).
  ```
- > Questions asking for **programming help** are off-topic unless they involve tools designed to program quantum computers or quantum computer emulations. Please see [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-questions-about-q-on-topic) meta question. You may get help at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

  ```
  Questions asking for **programming help** are off-topic unless they involve tools designed to program quantum computers or quantum computer emulations. Please see [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-questions-about-q-on-topic) meta question. You may get help at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).
  ```

  *or*

  > Questions asking for **programming help** are off-topic unless they are directly related to quantum computers or quantum computing algorithms. Please see [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-questions-about-q-on-topic) meta question. You may get help at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

  ```
  Questions asking for **programming help** are off-topic unless they involve tools designed to program quantum computers or quantum computer emulations. Please see [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-questions-about-q-on-topic) meta question. You may get help at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).
  ```
- > Questions asking us **to provide a list of resources** have to follow [strict rules specified by the community](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed) to be considered on-topic.

  ```
  Questions asking us **to provide a list of resources** have to follow [strict rules specified by the community](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed) to be considered on-topic.
  ```

  *or, if the community decides not to allow list questions*

  > Questions asking us **to provide a list of resources** are by [community decision](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed) off-topic.

  ```
  Questions asking us **to provide a list of resources** are by [community decision](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed) off-topic.
  ```
- > Questions about **computer science** and related topics are off-topic unless they involve its application to quantum computers. You may get help at [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

  ```
  Questions about **computer science** and related topics are off-topic unless they involve its application to quantum computers. You may get help at [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).
  ```

Comment: We might want to write a more general meta q/a for quantum programming languages, and you may also wish to provide a referral to SO. Another close reason should probably have to do with pure CS questions (as you have several pure physics close reasons).

Comment: @heather I don't have several pure physics close reasons, just one with several variants. And if you want to add your own close reason, feel free to edit it, its community wiki

Comment: Of the suggestions about **quantum mechanics** I prefer the first version; _application to quantum computers_ is a bit more open which, especially in such a new field, is a good thing. We can always limit it further if we run into problems.
From the versions on **programming help** I'd go for the second one for the same reason - more open, thus potentially allowing more questions.

Comment: @heather hello could you new mods please reconsider my request now. Especially as you have access to off-topic closure reasons and can therefore easily select the three most often used reasons/question types.

Comment: @MEE Mithrandir26401 and I have discussed this and we agreed that it's a little early for off-topic reasons - currently only four questions have been closed, and that's not enough to see trends.

Comment: @heather ok thanks for the info.