# Should code highlighting be enabled on this site to improve code readability?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I've seen some posts that include code (Python, Q# (see [Are questions about Q# on topic?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-questions-about-q-on-topic))):

- Q: [How to create an arbitrary state in QISKit for a local_qasm_simulator?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1413/609) (+ [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1431/23))
- Q: [There was an error in the circuit!. Error = 'QISkit Time Out'](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1247/609) (+ 2 answers)
- A: [What would a very simple quantum program look like?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1442/609) (+ other answer)

**The question is:** Do we need code highlighting on this site to improve the code readability?

---

**Edit:**

As an extension to this, to make it more up to date, there have since been other questions where it could potentially be useful, specifically using the [qiskit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qiskit) tag:

- Q: [Construct Controlled-$G^†$
  from known Controlled-$G$](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2469/23) (+ [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2470/23))
- Q: [One-qubit gates results in QISKit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2454/23)
- A: [Quantum algorithm for linear systems of equations (HHL09): Step 2 - Preparation of the initial states $|Ψ_0⟩$
  and $|b⟩$](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2464/23)
- A: [Changing indices of qubits in QISKit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2360/23)
- Q: [Composing multiple quantum circuits in single quantum program in QISKit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2242/23)
- A: [How can I implement an n-bit Toffoli gate?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2178/23)

As well as a few other examples that use a smaller amount of code

Comment: Is there code-highlighting on other sites on SE?

Comment: @Discretelizard [so], [codereview.se], [su], maybe some other.

Comment: While (in my opinion) it would be nice, it's very likely that [Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) (what SE uses for this) doesn't have full Q# highlighting, so we'd be limited to standard C# syntax highlighting

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Actually, Q# syntax resembles F# a lot more than C#.

Comment: I've edited the title to more clearly reflect the request being made.

Answer (score 10):

- StackOverflow has syntax highlighting, but does not have $\LaTeX$, that makes it difficult to reason about the code in terms of $|quantum\rangle \otimes |states\rangle$.
- This community has $\LaTeX$ but does not yet offer syntax highlighting, that everyone has got used to these days.

A community that gets both would be a perfect place for Q&A on quantum computing libraries/languages.

Moreover, the libraries/languages that implement quantum computing concepts have become essential tools for quantum computing researchers.

So, I vote for syntax highlighting.

Comment: I wrote an answer to Nat's question about MathJax and proposed that we implement Qcircuit, as is used on some other sites (but not SE), to write quantum gates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate so that the rendered images are editable. See here: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/152/278 .

Answer (score 2):

The feedback below has historical significance ever since we changed from the Google Prettyfier to : ["Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/282094), see here for more information: ["What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/282094).

Even ***if*** it was enabled, its [support for Quantum Computing languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/282094) is little or next to none; since using an incorrect hint can provide partial highlighting in some instances. There are [no 3rd party](https://github.com/search?q=quantum+highlighting+language) projects implementing any Quantum Computing languages, and even [when languages are supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355928/282094) they are not always enabled.

Requests that affect a single site are [usually declined](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/a/193/516), but for [a workaround](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/a/194/516) the highlighting for another language can be substituted.

Historical Feedback:

We might want Highlighting in the future, the FAQ ([Markdown Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)) shows that it adds useful features. It will be a question of how much code there will be, which languages, and how much BTS we can help with.

The SE sites use [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) only.

In the Meta.SE post [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) it is written:

> "(all specific languages must be in the set that prettify supports, obviously)

> bsh, c, cc, cpp, cs, csh, cyc, cv, htm, html, java, js, m, mxml, perl, pl, pm, py, rb, sh, xhtml, xml, xsl.

> extensions available are

> apollo, css, go, hs, lisp, lua, ml, proto, scala, sql, vb, vhdl, wiki, yaml".

> Posted by: Jeff Atwood, Locked by: Shog9.

Glimmer of hope: Diamond moderators can now change syntax highlighting on a per-tag per-site basis. We're also looking at an in-source override syntax soon. – Jeff Atwood Feb 21 '11 at 22:27

---

Google **[Prettify FAQ](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md)**

- For which languages does it work?

The comments in prettify.js are authoritative but the lexer should work on a number of languages including C and friends, Java, Python, Bash, SQL, HTML, XML, CSS, JavaScript, Makefile, and Rust.

It works passably on Ruby, PHP, VB, and Awk and a decent subset of Perl and Ruby, but because of commenting conventions, doesn't work on Smalltalk, OCaml, etc. without a language extension.

Other languages are supported via extensions:

Apollo; Basic; Clojure; CSS; Dart; Erlang; Go; Haskell; Lasso; Lisp, Scheme; LLVM; Logtalk; Lua; MATLAB; MLs: F#, Ocaml,SML; Mumps; Nemerle; Pascal; Protocol buffers; R, S; RD; Rust; Scala; SQL; Swift; TCL; LaTeX; Visual Basic; VHDL; Wiki; XQ; YAML

If you'd like to add an extension for your favorite language, please look at src/lang-lisp.js and submit a pull request.

---

So ...

Step 1: Write the extension for each language we are going to support.

Step 2: Submit your extension.

Step 3: Convince SE to activate Highlighting here, and use your extensions.

Note: Here is a question that features Highlighting: "[PyObject_CallMethod Returns Null, Simple Example Provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725393/pyobject-callmethod-returns-null-simple-example-provided)", nothing is clickable nor does it have a run button. For the work involved getting Highlighting here we might just work on a *MathJaxifier* Script that highlights the code offline for copy/pasting.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax highlighting is now enabled on your site. Note that there is no default language currently selected, so site moderators will need to select one on a per-tag basis.

Mods: Not a super hard process. Go to any tag's page, click "Learn more..." and you should see the options there.

> [image: Circled "learn more" on a tag page.]

And the controls...

> [image: Circled the default syntax highlight language controls on the per-tag page.]

Answer (score -1):

In only one of the pages referenced, we have a rather large codeblock and even that one is perfectly readable without syntax highlighting.

I don't think there are going to be much questions or answers with large codeblocks and hence I don't think that syntax highlighting is required (it most certainly isn't as essential as $\LaTeX$ support)